# Generate a "Create Table" script in Toad / SQL Navigator

Tags: sql-server, toad, create-table, sql-navigator

I know that in SQL Server Management Studio you have the ability to right click on any table and are able to select `Script Table As` > `CREATE To` and are then able to get the entire create statement for any object in your DB.

Does anyone know if there's a similar functionality in Toad / [SQL Navigator](https://www.toadworld.com/products/sql-navigator)?

Comment: Why the downvote?
This is a legitimate question someone on this community would know the answer to.....

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question. This is a question about a tool commonly used by developers, and it's perfectly acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Toad, select your table in the object navigator then right-click and select "Create Script".

There are various options to select that control what is included in that script too.

Comment: Gary is spot on. There are also many other ways to get this in Toad as well. The script tab on the right side of the Schema Browser has it as well, but w/o the creation options in Gary's method. The Create Script method utilizes Toad's Export DDL functionality which you can get to from the Database|Export menu as well.

Comment: For whatever reason, I couldn't get that to work on SQL Navigator, but, using the comment above, I also managed to do it there using the `Extract DDL` > `Code Editor` > `SQL Scripts` - Hope this helps someone else too...

Answer (score 2):

Although @Gary's answer above works in Toad, just for the sake of completeness, I wanted to mention that in SQL Navigator, I couldn't get it working as-is and, so, managed to do it using:

```
Extract DDL > Code Editor > SQL Scripts
```

Hope this helps someone else too..